# Suppose that X~geom(p) and the conditional distribution of y given X=x is poisson with mean x. Find E(Y) and Var(Y).

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

Suppose that X~geom(p) and the conditional distribution of y given X=x is poisson with mean x. Find E(Y) and Var(Y).

I know that
Var(Y)=E(Y^2)-(E(Y)^2) but I don't know how to start with finding E(Y).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

> but I don't know how to start with finding E(Y).

Start with the Law of Total Expectation (LoTE), sometimes called the Law of Iterated Expectation, or the Tower Property.

$$\mathsf E(Y)=\mathsf E(\mathsf E(Y\mid X))$$

---

Similarly $\mathsf E(Y^2)~{=\mathsf E(\mathsf E(Y^2\mid X))\\=\mathsf E(\mathsf{Var}(Y\mid X)+\mathsf E(Y\mid X)^2)}$

$\qquad\vdots$

So $\mathsf {Var}(Y)=\mathsf E(\mathsf{Var}(Y\mid X))+\mathsf{Var}(\mathsf E(Y\mid X))$